# How do I detect user's usage of other apps like the Forest App?

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, android-lifecycle, observers

I'm currently working on a focus timer app in the vein of Forest, and I've been having some trouble with working with the state of the app.

The idea is that I'm trying to send notifications to the User when they leave the app to return to the home-screen, or while they're using other apps. I am currently accomplishing this using Android's LifeCycleObserver.

```
@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE)
fun onAppBackgrounded() {
    //App in background
    //send notifications
}

@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
fun onAppForegrounded() {
    //code running
    //stop sending notification
}
```

The current issue with this is that it does not differentiate between the app going to onPause() when the User leaves the app and the app going to onPause() when their phone is put to sleep, and

I was thinking that if instead, I observed the User's usage of other apps (like Forest does), I could use that to send notifications instead. However I am unaware of how to do this. If anyone could shed light on how Forest handles this app detection stuff, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: What would the app do if user killed it but still use another one? Stop sending notifications or not?

Comment: It should just stop. It's not meant to send notifications while not in use.

Answer (score 0):

As described in comment section, I think it is unnecessary to detect if the phone is using another app or not. You finally want your app to send notifications when it gets in background, means that anytime an activity falls into stopped state (`onStop()` is called) but `onDestroy()` is not called after a few seconds, the notifications should be sent. Therefor, using `Handler.postDelay()` is a trick to achieve that.

```
val handler = Handler()
  
override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    handler.postDelayed({ () -> sendNotification()},500) //500 milliseconds
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)  //remove sending notifications task from message queue of main thread if onDestroy was called immediately after onStop.
}
```

Comment: I only want it to send notifications when it goes to the background a specific way. From what I understand (and this might be a mistake on my part), when the phone is put to sleep, the app is considered to be in the background. However, I do not want to send notifications in this scenario. I am correct in thinking this?

Comment: @AnhTran To the best of my knowledge, Android OS will trigger a broadcast named SCREEN_OFF  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_SCREEN_OFF when the phone gets in sleep mode (black screen and non-interactive). You can combine my answer above with the broadcast to control more behaviors in your app.

Comment: E cảm ơn anh =))